# Pasting does not work in Network share

Tags: ubuntu, nas, nfs, smb

i have a weird problem on my Ubuntu 20.04.1 Notebook. I can write in shares from my server but i can't paste. That means i can create a new folder or file but the paste button with right-click is grayed out.

This happens with all users and with all shares and even with smb and nfs.

I don't get what I'm doing wrong. I would probably get the files transferred with the terminal but thats not a solution to the problem.

The shares are from a Unraid 6.9.2 server, but it works from my Mint and Windows machine fine.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try using Shift-Insert or Ctrl-Shift-V.

Answer (score 0):

It'd seem like a problem with Ubuntu 20.04: [Source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1241475/cut-paste-or-copy-paste-not-working-on-ubuntu-20-04-on-using-right-click-context)

Have you tried other OSs? Can you run a VM with 20.10 ( or later ) to see if it's been fixed since?